# Is Bootstrap 3 RC 1 ready for production?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm beginning a huge project today and I had chosen Zurb's Foundation because of their (very) good Mobile first strategy. When I started shopping around some months ago, Bootstrap 3 wasn't nearly ready. But I checked it today (July the 30th) and their have RC1 available.

<strike>Should I use it instead of Zurb's Foundation?</strike>
Why should i use or not use a Release Candidate? And what are the difference between Twitter's Bootstrap and Zurb's Foundation?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15562436/use-zurb-foundation-4-twitter-bootstrap-3-for-non-mobile-first-project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the name tells you a release candidate is never ready for production. But the release of Bootstrap 3 seems to be planned on august 19th 2013 (see: http://blog.getbootstrap.com/).
The mobile first strategy is no argument to choose cause TB3 also has this now.

Make a list of differences between both frameworks and compare these with your wishes and capabilities.

**Zurb's Foundation**       /                **Twitter's Bootstrap 3**

MIT Open Source License        /              Apache 2.0 license

Sass   (SCSS)                  /                        Less

[Foundation-icons](http://zurb.com/playground/foundation-icons) / [Glyphicons](http://glyphicons.getbootstrap.com/)

[Javascript components](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/abide.html) / [Javascript Plugins](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/)

etc.

Good luck

PS Hi @Draconar i can't choose for you, but when i was you is should start my project with TB3RC1. Cause this is a RC i don't expect major changes for the final release. As you mentioned TB has a big helpful community so i don't expect you will hit a dead end ever.
But when you don't want to take this risk i should prefer ZF above Twitter's Bootstrap 2.
Twitter's Bootstrap 3 is not backward compatible with Twitter's Bootstrap 2 so migration will always hurts you.
There will be one moment you will need a new feature which TB2 not have or support always in future.
I also so have to tell you i don't know ZF very well, so i can't tell you much about their community or support.
I will advice you to read this too: [Use Zurb Foundation 4 / Twitter Bootstrap 3 For Non Mobile First Projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15562436/use-zurb-foundation-4-twitter-bootstrap-3-for-non-mobile-first-projects)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the insightful answer. My worries are: I'm a noobie in both frameworks (haven't really used them more than following tutorials) and:

- I'm afraid that Foundation has not community support, so I may hit some dead end and not be able to move fast

- Bootstrap3 being too green and solutions made for the Version 2.4 will not work anyway and I will hit a dead end...

what are your thoughts?

Comment: see update of my answer

Answer (score 1):

It is not ready for production. There are still plenty of tiny bugs to iron out and more are reported as people are testing.

However, if you are happy to develop using a somewhat changing set of framework code, then it might be worth it and by the time you are ready for production the final version Bootstrap 3 may be out.