# Bootstrap 3 IE9 dropdown not working

Tags: internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a simple site I put together for a relative which I am currently working on. It is in a very simple state at the minute until I get out of them what they actually want. So the site is here http://www.ajglass.co.uk/ everything works fine on IE10 and FF. I tried it on IE9 and the drop down doesn't show,  I am using bootstrap 3 RC1 and the latest jquery.

Any ideas what the issue could be?

Comment: Don't use RC release code for a production site.

Comment: Also dropdown is working in IE 9 here - make sure you're not running in some weird quirks mode or rendering it as IE 7 etc...

Comment: I thought the RC would be fine as I don't use much of the functionality and thought it would save me changing later. Also the site is extremely basic. My IE9 is running on IE9 mode with IE 9 standards, strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As told by [Ryan McDonough](https://stackoverflow.com/users/442624/ryan-mcdonough) don't use the RC for a production site. Make sure you got the latest version from https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap. Compile with Bower or Grunt. Read: [Is Bootstrap 3 RC 1 ready for production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981716/is-bootstrap-3-rc-1-ready-for-production/17983268).

Also read this link cause you use "row-fluid" which is not used in Twitter's Boostrap 3 any more: [Updating Bootstrap to version 3 - what do I have to do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17974998/updating-bootstrap-to-version-3-what-do-i-have-to-do/18069643)

And consider: ["JavaScript placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster" TRUE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547062/javascript-placed-at-the-end-of-the-document-so-the-pages-load-faster-true)

It seems you use TB3 CSS and JS with HTML for TB2.

Comment: Yeah you are both right, bit silly using RC code. I tested with bootsrap 2.3 on IE9 and the dropdown is fine. I will move the site back to this. Thanks.