# Use Twitter Bootstrap 3 or Foundation 5 to all compatible project

Tags: frameworks, twitter-bootstrap-3, zurb-foundation

I want to make project which must compatible for all device (desktop, mobile, and tablet).

I try look foundation 5 on IE 7, and the result is bad interface. but bootstrap 3, its still looking good.

But I not yet analyze for another things for example SEO better, light framework, mobile/tablet/desktop bug, newest technology.

Could anyone please to share about the above things? thanks

Comment: Bootstrap 3 is not compatible with IE7 (it looks bad in IE7) it works in IE8 with certain script addtions. I don't believe you're going to find such a framework for all devices and all browsers. Most frameworks and themes support modern browsers on modern devices and should (if specified in their docs) degrade gracefully enough to be functional, yet not look the same or even look any good on older devices with older browsers. JQuery 2x doesn't support any IE browser older than 9 (current is 11).

Comment: @ChristinaArasmoBeymer: could you help to give best suggestion?

Comment: also read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981716/is-bootstrap-3-rc-1-ready-for-production/17983268 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20615535/twitter-bootstrap-support-for-ie7/20619104#20619104

Comment: It depends on the project. If you need ie7 support -- which has less than 1% use worldwide usage -- then Bootstrap 2.3.2. If you don't need it, then Bootstrap 3.0.3 or the latest version. Read all the docs, download the samples. Try out the examples in various browsers and devices. Learn a good CMS, if it's a bigish project that needs database support. Amp up your CSS and html5 skills with http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/web, and/or TeamTreehouse, Lynda.com or another service. Get some basic jQuery under your belt.

Answer (score 4):

You can check [this blog post](https://medium.com/frontend-and-beyond/8b3812c7007c) comparing both frameworks, but this says all:

> ZURB and Twitter made their objectives and intentions very clear when
>   naming each CSS Frameworks: Bootstrap tries to give you everything
>   you’ll ever need to bootstrap your project. Foundation just gives you
>   the foundation to build upon.